# Where does Apache install httpd.conf by default?

Tags: linux, apache, centos, httpd.conf

I thought Apache's httpd.conf is typically located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.  But for my installation as described below on Centos 6.4, it is located at `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.  On top of that, DocumentRoot is set to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` instead of the traditional `/var/www/html`.

Where is the most common location for these to be located?  If different than what I am showing, what did I do wrong?  Thank you

First I did the following:

1. Unpack Apache 2.4.4 to /usr/local/src
2. Unpack APR 1.4.6 to /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.4/srclib/apr
3. Unpack APR-Util 1.5.2  to /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.4/srclib /apr-util
4. Unpack PCRE 8.33 to /usr/local/src

Then I did the following

```
$ cd /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.4/srclib/apr
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
$ cd /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.4/srclib/ apr-util
$ ./configure --with-apr=../apr (verify if any other options are desired)
$ make 
$ make install 
$ cd /usr/local/src/pcre-8.33
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ make install 
$ cd /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.4
$ ./configure --enable-so –enable-rewrite –enable-ssl –with-pcre
$ make 
$ make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did "wrong" was to not read the documentation, which [clearly states](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html):

> PREFIX must be replaced with the filesystem path under which the server should be installed. If PREFIX is not specified, it defaults to /usr/local/apache2.

However, I put "wrong" in quotes because I cannot find anything wrong with those directories. What's so bad about `/usr/local`?

Comment: Thanks innaM.  I did read (and re-read) the documentation, but didn't realize this applied to httpd.conf.  After a 3rd read, it does seem pretty clear.  What is bad about `/usr/local`?  In the past, I always saw it located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.  Where is the most common or proper location?

Comment: Manually installed software should usually not pollute system directories. Apache is well behaved in this respect. Install Apache why your distributions package management system and the paths should look more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no problem with `httpd.conf` in `/usr/local`. The only problem will be that others will not be expecting it there so they might become confused.
Rest is okay. While compiling you should have mentioned `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but it should not be a problem.

Did you have any particular reason for compiling Apache and not using `yum`?
If you used `yum`, the file would have automatically landed in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: Why install from source?  Because this is how I interpreted that the documentation wanted me to do so.  Is this not correct?  Thanks http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html

Comment: The option of compilation is always there, but that does not mean that you have to use it every time. You mentioned CentOS 6.4, I always install apache from yum on CentOS even on critical production servers. And I never face a problem. Of course, sometimes compilation is the only option, like one time I have to install apache on a cPanel Server, and no other option was available for latest version.